# Usage of local variables

Tags: r, scope

**Problem:**

How to define local variables within a scope in a r-code.

**Example:**

In C++ the following example defines a scope, and variables declared within the scope are undefined in outside code.

```
{
     vector V1 = getVector(1);
     vector V1(= getVector(2);
     double P = inner_product(V1, V2);
     print(P);
}
// the variable V1, V2, P are undefined here!
```

*Note: This code is only to illustrate the idea.*

This practice has the advantages of:

- Keeping the global namespace clean;
- simplifying code;
- removing ambiguities, specially when a variable is re-used without initialization.

In R, it seems to me that this notion is only existent inside function definitions. So, in order to reproduce the previous example code, I would need to do something like this:

```
dummy <- function( ) {
     V1 = c(1,2,3);
     V2 = c(1,2,3);
     P = inner_product(V1, V2);
     print(P);
}
dummy( );
# the variable V1, V2, P are undefined here!
```

or, in an even more obscure way, declare a anonymous function to prevent the function call:

```
(function() { 
     V1 = c(1,2,3);
     V2 = c(1,2,3);
     P = inner_product(V1, V2);
     print(P);
})()
# the variable V1, V2, P are undefined here!
```

**Question**

Is there a more elegant way to create local variable?

Comment: There is no function in the default packages named inner_product but using ordinary vector "*" should give you that. This: `(function() { 
     V1 = c(1,2,3);
     V2 = c(1,2,3);
     P = V1*V2;
     print(P);
})()` gives `#[1] 1 4 9`. I fail to understand why that is any less clear or simple than the C++ version. If your code is throwing errors, it is not because of scoping issues, but because you are ignoring error messages. If that is not what you are saying with your exclamatory comment then you need to explain further.

Comment: it was mentioned that the code was just to illustrate the question, and not to deal with inner product. The second comment gives better answer, which consist to the usage of the  'local' construct, such as local({ c=c(1,2,3); d=c(2,3,4);e = c*d; print(e) })

Comment: I'm afraid I still do not understand what is meant by "variables V1, V2, P are undefined here!".

Comment: It means that the variable are not defined in that scope. For example, the code: `local({ v=c(1,2,3); })` will produce an error `Error in print(v) : object 'v' not found`, if one tries to use v outside the local block.
> print(v)
Error in print(v) : object 'v' not found

Answer (score 13, accepted):

Use `local`. Using your example:

```
local({ 
     V1 = c(1,2,3);
     V2 = c(1,2,3);
     P = inner_product(V1, V2);
     print(P);
})
# the variable V1, V2, P are undefined here!
```

Answer (score 1):

You can create a new `environment` where your variable can be defined; this is how the local scope within a function is defined.

You can read more about this [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf)

check the help for `environment` as well i.e. type in your R console `?environment`