# Which scope rule do R and C# differ in this case?

Tags: c#, r, scope

Can someone point out which scope rule do C# and R differ so that they produce different result in the following examples?

C#

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var funs = new Action<string>[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        {
            funs[j] = x => Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
    }
    funs[2]("foo"); // prints 2
}
```

R

```
funclist <- list()
for(i in 1:5)
{
  {
    j<-i
    funclist[[j]] <- function(x) print(j)
  } // the 5 inner blocks share the same scope?
}

funclist[[2]]('foo') // prints 5
```

#### Update

This question is helpful [R: usage of local variables](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14793113/r-usage-of-local-variables/14793252)

I believe I found out the difference - In R there is **NO document saying that a block would create a new scope.** So only function can create a new scope, for loop cannot, brackets cannot.

Any one can give me a link to some definitive guide in R that clearly states brackets other than functions would NOT create a new scope?

Comment: I am unfamiliar with R, but here is a clarifying question. If you said `i<-1 / j<-i / i<-2 / print(j)` would you get 1 or 2? Is `j` an *alias* for `i` or is it a *copy* of `i`?

Comment: @EricLippert, in that case, you would get the value `1`. R copies by value.  The issue is that the object `j` when evaluating the function is not the same `j` when the function was created.

Comment: The section on `lazy evaluation` [**here on hadley's wiki**](https://github.com/hadley/devtools/wiki/Functions) may also shed some light wrt R.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm not sure about `C#`, but as for `R`, the functions are evaluated lazily.

The `j` in `print(j)` does not get evaluated until the time the function gets called. Thus when you call `funclist[[2]]('foo')` only *then* does `R` search for the value of `j`, which when last left off, was 5.  However, try the following and you'll see the value is not related to the loop at all.

```
j <- "Some Other Value"
funclist[[2]]('foo')
```

#### Update regarding question in the comment

In `R`, a for loop does not affect the scope or environment. (On the other hand, `functions` and `apply` like loops do).    Thus to clarify, you **cannot** initialize a variable inside of a nested * environment* and access it from the *parent* environment [1]. You can however do the opposite; that is access the objects of a parent's environment from within the children environment.

As is clearly depicted in this picture in Ross Ihaka's sign 
[image: Ross Ihaka & Robert Gentleman]
source: http://www.nytimes.com/2009/01/07/technology/business-computing/07program.html?pagewanted=all

For more on scoping in R, see:
 http://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Fox-Companion/appendix-scope.pdf

[1] The statement above is not altogether true. You **can** access such a variable using the `get(.., envir=..)` function. But you cannot access it directly in the way you can access parent's objects from inside nested functions.

Comment: In R, what is the scope of `j`? To be clear, since this word is used to mean many different things, by "what is the scope of `j`?" I mean "what is *the region of program text in which it is legal to refer to variable `j` by name?"  Your answer implies that `j` can be initialized inside two nested blocks, and yet used outside. How far out does it go? Is `j` "in scope" throughout the entire program?

Comment: @EricLippert Perhaps more concisely: assuming the OP's code is run as is in a fresh R session, `j` could "legally" be referred to (i.e. R will find and return a value, rather than throw an error) at any point after a value is assigned to it. So anytime after `j <- i` the first time through the `for` loop.

Answer (score 3):

I don't know anything about R but I can tell you what is happening in C# here.

In C# when you enter a function you get an *activation* of that function; that "activation" keeps track of the state of all the variables and temporary values used by that invocation of the function.  This is how functions can be recursive; each call gets its own activation, and so can have its own local variable values.

In C#, this idea that functions get their own activations *actually extends to blocks*.  When you say:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var funs = new Action<string>[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        int j = i;
        {
            funs[j] = x => Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
    }
    funs[2]("foo"); // prints 2
}
```

That is logically just as though you'd said

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var funs = new Action<string>[5];
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
        D(i, funs);
    funs[2]("foo"); // prints 2
}

static void D(int i, Action<string>[] funs)
{
    int j = i;
    {
        funs[j] = x => Console.WriteLine(j);
    }
}
```

Every time you go through the loop you get *a brand new variable `j`* which the lambda closes over.

I suspect that what is happening in R is that instead of getting a brand new `j` every time through the loop you are *updating the previous `j`*, which is not at all what C# does. That is, it seems like your R program is in fact equivalent to:

```
public static void Main(string[] args)
{
    var funs = new Action<string>[5];
    int j;
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++)
    {
        j = i;
        {
            funs[j] = x => Console.WriteLine(j);
        }
    }
    funs[2]("foo");
}
```

Which prints 4, because that's the last value that j ever takes on.

See http://ericlippert.com/2009/11/12/closing-over-the-loop-variable-considered-harmful-part-one/ for more details.

Comment: Can I say in C#, a local variable declaration space always contains its scope (scope is a subset of declaration space w.r.t. a variable), and hence any creation of new declaration space means the creation of new scope?

Comment: If you care to, you can read more details about R's lexical scoping [here](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/r-release/R-intro.html#Scope).

Comment: @colinfang: For *local variable declaration spaces* there is a tight relationship between declaration space and scope. The *region in which a variable may be named* and *the region in which nothing else may have that name* are the same for local variables. That is not true in general; the *scope* of a protected field of class includes all subclasses, but the *declaration space* does not.

Answer (score 3):

To expand a bit on @RicardoSaporta's answer.

In R run the command:

```
environment(funclist[[2]])
```

and you will see that the parent environment for the function(s) is the global environment, so since `j` is never made local to the functions, when they run they will not find any variable named `j` in the local environment, so the next thing they will do is to look in the enclosing environment, which is the global environment and use whatever the current value of `j` is there.  If you do `rm(j)` then run any of the functions you will get an error that it cannot find `j`.

If you want each of the functions to have its own enclosing environment with different values of `j` then you can do something like:

```
funclist <- list()
for(i in 1:5)
{
   funclist[[i]] <- local( {
    j <- i
    function(x) print(j)
    } )
}

funclist[[2]]('foo') # prints 2
```

Answer (score 2):

[Section 3.5 of *R Language Definition*](http://cran.r-project.org/doc/manuals/R-lang.html#Scope-of-variables) describes the scoping rules for variables in R.

In section 3.5.2 it states

> Every call to a function creates a frame which contains the local variables created in the function, and is evaluated in an environment, which in combination creates a new environment.

So it is (only) the calling of a function which creates a new lexical scope. Within a function, you can create additional scopes by calling other functions (and, in fact, see the help on the [`local()`](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/base/html/eval.html) function for a function whose sole purpose is to create a new scope).

So scoping in R, unlike C++, is only at the function level, not the block level.

Answer (score 1):

I think `C#` way of execution is procedural. All the functions arguments are evaluated at the time of creation of list.

In `R` function arguments are evaluated only when the function is called for the first time. That means when `funclist[[2]]('foo')` is called, the `for` loop is already evaluated and `j` has last value `5`.

Note: one can use `force` which will result in `C#` like behavior.